# JSON: retrieving data from http

Tags: javascript, json

I am new in JSON. This is the code that I make an attempt to retrieve data from http Json. But it doesn't display anything when I run it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript">

function ajaxRequest(){
 var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"] //activeX versions to check for in IE
 if (window.ActiveXObject){ //Test for support for ActiveXObject in IE first (as XMLHttpRequest in IE7 is broken)
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
   try{
    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])

   }
   catch(e){
    //suppress error
   }
  }
 }
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
 else
  return false
}

</script>
<title>Retrieving Json FILE</title>
</head>
<body>
<span>Demo:</span>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var mygetrequest=new ajaxRequest()
mygetrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mygetrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mygetrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   var jsondata=eval("("+mygetrequest.responseText+")") //retrieve result as an JavaScript object
   var rssentries=jsondata.items
   var output='<ul>'
   for (var i=0; i<rssentries.length; i++){
    output+='<li>'
    output+='<a href="'+rssentries[i].link+'">'
    output+=rssentries[i].title+'</a>'
    output+='</li>'
   }
   output+='</ul>'
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=output
   alert("it is running")
  }
  else{
   alert("An error has occured making the request")
  }
 }
}

mygetrequest.open("GET", "javascriptkit.json", true)
mygetrequest.send(null)

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use jQuery or some other framework to do Ajax.

Comment: Is this request being made on the domain where the JavaScript is hosted on?

Comment: @Luca: respectively disagree. There's really no need.

Comment: You cannot retrieve pure JSON from another domain due to the *same-origin policy*. You'd have to use JSONP.

Comment: This is most likely a case of cross-domain AJAX. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024294/cross-domain-limitations-with-ajax-json

Comment: Is this page hosted on `breathecast.com` because if not you might be hitting cross domain restrictions.

Comment: I would suggest looking at jQuery and the getJSON features

Comment: Fancy libraries like jQuery are just fine but they should not replace basic JavaScript knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this:

```
 new ajaxRequest('http://breathecast.com/lewis/xml_json.php?format=json')
```

... you must actually use the argument:

```
function ajaxRequest(url){
    // Do something with URL
}
```

Compare with what you have, which is basically:

```
function ajaxRequest(){
    // URL is never used
}
```

If you enable the code you commented out:

```
mygetrequest.open("GET", "http://breathecast.com/lewis/xml_json.php?format=json", true)
mygetrequest.send(null)
```

... you'll see your script is finally doing something. In my case, I get the `An error has occured making the request` alert because my test page is not located at `http://breathecast.com/` and you cannot use `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch data from other domains.

Comment: It's still not displaying anything.

Comment: @Lewis Since your code is wrong for the reasons I stated, it's pretty normal that it won't work properly until it's fixed.

Comment: I have fix the code and update the question, but it still not showing? is it have to do with server?