# jQuery / Ajax fetches local but not remote pages

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

I still don't get why this code works fine when loading local server pages (localhost) but display nothing when trying to fetch remote data

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get(
    "message.html",
    function(data) { $("div").html(data); },
    "html"
    );
});
```

and displaying the remote html file gives me no error but no data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get(
    "http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html",
    function(data) { $("div").html(data); },
    "html"
    );
});
```

Regards

Comment: maybe duplication here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin`

Comment: doesn't seem like it. His problem is that he's trying to do cross-domain requests with ajax, which isn't allowed. He'll have to make a serverside page on the same domain that makes the call out and then returns the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built-in restriction to prevent cross-domain Ajax requests from the browser. Pretty much all browsers implement this.

There are workarounds such as the article [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) or using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). But this is a basic restriction put on Ajax requests sent from the browser. If you are using ASP.NET Encosia also had a good tip on doing the [proxying using a custom HttpHandler](http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/).

See also: [Cross Domain Limitations With Ajax - JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024294/cross-domain-limitations-with-ajax-json)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){
 
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function(data){
          $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
            if ( i == 3 ) return false;
          });
        });
});`